# Vuetify App bar is below the contents. How do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

[image: before scroll.]

[image: while scrolls down.]

i'm using Vuetify.js.

When I scroll down, the contents covers the app-bar.

I think simply set z-index causes a lot of problems.

[example codepen](https://codepen.io/devflow/pen/PoqOVNZ)

my app structure (pseudo)

```
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar app absolute shrink-on-scroll prominent scroll-target"#a">
  <v-sheet id="a" overflow-y-auto>
    <v-content>
      <keep-alive>
        <router-view>
          ..
            <v-container>
              <v-col>
                <v-expansion-panels>
                  ...
          ..

  <v-footer>
```

Comment: please add debugable example like [this](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/rNVYPOv)

Comment: Please provide all of the relevant code to demonstrated the issue

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thanks for advice. jsut add codepen link :D

Comment: add this CSS rule `.v-sheet {
 
    z-index: 0;
}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It works! But is it really a good idea to set z-index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `absolute` prop from `v-app-bar` component :

```
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar app  shrink-on-scroll prominent scroll-target"#a">
  <v-sheet id="a" overflow-y-auto>
```

check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/eYBOoPR)